# Log4j not send logs to linux SYSLOG

Tags: java, log4j, syslog

I want implement log4j to my java project. I put the jar in lib folder and configure log4j.properties file. Logs successfuly shows in console, but I can't see that logs in SYSLOG app (KSYSLOG) of my kubuntu. this is my properties file:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, SYSLOG, file

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Redirect log messages to a SYSLOG
log4j.appender.SYSLOG=org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.syslogHost=127.0.0.1
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.layout.conversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%t] %c{2} %x - %m%n
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.Facility=LOCAL1

# Redirect log messages to a log file, support file rolling.
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=/var/log/  log4j-application.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

what is incorrect in this properties file or what I do incorrect?

Comment: Does it work with `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: @DraganBozanovic no, same problem

Answer (score 0):

I found the solutin in this thread [Writing log data to syslog using log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13234727/writing-log-data-to-syslog-using-log4j)

we must add

```
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514
```

to rsyslog.conf and restart rsyslog

Comment: can you provide more info? Where is the file you edited?

Comment: @StealthRabbi /etc/rsyslog.conf