# What is Log4j 1.x's 'log4j.rootCategory'?

Tags: log4j

I've been struggling for weeks to upgrade Log4j from 1.x to 2.x.  By far the biggest difficulty is converting the configuration, which the Log4j authors changed completely between versions without fully documenting how to migrate.

For example, my application currently uses Log4j 1.x with a `log4j.properties` file that starts with the following line:

```
log4j.rootCategory=WARN, CONSOLE
```

In order to convert this to Log4j 2.x configuration syntax, I have to first understand its meaning within the context of Log4j 1.x configuration syntax.  This does not appear to be possible.

The Log4j [2.x Configuration Guide](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Properties) does not contain a reference to `log4j.rootCategory` or any other information that helps me understand its meaning.

The Log4j [Migration Guide](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html) from 1.x to 2.x does not contain a reference to `log4j.rootCategory` or any other information that helps me understand its meaning.

I've searched for Log4j 1.x configuration documentation for two days now, and I've found nothing useful.  I performed web searches for "log4j convert syntax", "log4j 1.x config documentation", "log4j.rootCategory documentation", "log4j rootCategory configuration" and more.  None of these returned anything other than the above links or other pages that do not contain a reference to `log4j.rootCategory` or any other information that helps me understand its meaning.

This [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39146562/6673905) question states that "The actual Documentation for the LOG4J version 1.x is offline."  This appears to be largely true, although @Tobias Otto provides a link to the Log4j 1.x manual at [logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html).  This page does have a perfunctory "Configuration" section, but it does not contain a reference to `log4j.rootCategory` or any other information that helps me understand its meaning.

I'm out of ideas.  What does setting `log4j.rootCategory` accomplish in the context of Log4j 1.x configuration syntax?  How is this goal accomplished in the context of Log4j 2.x configuration syntax?  Is there any meaningful documenation available for Log4j 1.x configuration directives?

Comment: Category is an outdated term for logger. You should see references to root logger in the doc.

Comment: @NathanHughes  This appears to be correct